# Is Better csv or sqlite for preload data into Core data?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data, csv

I have to preload data into my core data to have always my entities full of data, since the first time someone start the application. I have a database in csv and other sqlite. which is the best? and How should I do it? I mean, I guess I should have my database always in a folder of my app and the first time I launch the app I will fill data into database. isn't it? or I am wrong? if this is the good way? How I do it?

Comment: Maybe try the sqlite because the Core data may be able to instantly hook into the database and have the data already there.

Comment: @Tony-- that won't work. The SQLite schema won't be what Core Data wants.

Comment: See [How to Preload and Import Existing Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated) on Wenderlich's site. Bottom line, you might just want to distribute an app with the data preloaded into Core Data.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend an already mapped CoreData store. Whether it have been previously mapped by your app or by an editor such as Core Data Editor.

In the app delegate you can preload the data. In `- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator`.

You can remove the current store:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataStore.sqlite"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storeURL.path error:&error];
```

And you can move the preloaded store into place if there isn't already a store:

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataStore.sqlite"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {
    NSURL *preloadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PreloadData" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
    NSError* err = nil;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:preloadURL toURL:storeURL error:&err]) {
        NSLog(@"Oops, couldn't copy preloaded data");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of data you have. Really the only question that matters is which one fits your data better, because either works fine for writing code to import the data.

If your data contains entities of multiple types with relationships, SQLite will map that better than CSV. If not, use whatever you personally find most convenient to deal with.